# New python interpreter opens upon importing a package (control)

Tags: python

This is my first post so be gentle! I'm also in the process of learning python independently (trying to make engineering-related webapps using flask).

I have set up a project using virtualenv, and I've used the virtualenv-associated pip (what do I call this?) to install [control](http://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Now, when trying to play around with the control package to play around with it, I am running an instance of the virtualenv's python3 interpreter (I've tried doing this by using the python3 command with the virtualenv activated, and by executing the project's proj/bin/python3 command) and I `import control`.

Oddly, this opens another python interpreter running on my desktop. Here's the
[icon that appears on the mac doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goYFa.png).

Why is this **second interpreter** opening upon importing the control module?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is normal behavior on a Mac when an initially text-based Python session tries to initialize a GUI environment (apparently the matplotlib plotting library, in this case).

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense!

Unfortunately, my second interpreter isn't actually showing the plot (or any window, really). I imagine this is due to an error in my usage of the control package.